# Terminal/Shell Script for finding webcam status

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I am trying to make an Automator script on Mac that checks ever second to see if the builtin webcam is being used or not (so that I can automatically turn on my light if it is). I cannot seem to figure out an easy terminal/shell command to achieve this though